Shadcn/ui failing to build when importing tailwindcss in a remix app
following the documentation here: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/remix#6
I am getting the following exception:
app/root.tsx (11:7): "default" is not exported by "app/tailwind.css", imported by "app/root.tsx".
file: /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Projects/starwars/app/root.tsx:11:7

 9: import type { LinksFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
10: 
11: import styles from "./tailwind.css"
           ^
12: 
13: export const links: LinksFunction = () => [

the documentation explicitly states we need to import it rather than leave the remix string reference when importing the tailwind.css file.
This error does not stop development but does stop javascript from running, forcing server-side generation only. I also cannot run a npm run build, since this fails the compilation process.
feel free to see my example project with this problem here: https://github.com/ntregillus/starwars

With the new Vite compiler, there are now two ways to import stylesheets.
If you're using the links export, then you'll need to import the file by appending ?url to the filename:
import styles from "./tailwind.css?url"

styles is the path to the CSS file.
The other, and more idiomatic Vite way, is to simply use a side-effect import.
import "./tailwind.css"

Notice there is no variable. Vite will inline the styles during development, and will add an <link href> for production builds.
See https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/css-files for more info
